# mod_rewrite to change parts of a URL causes infinite loop error

Tags: mod-rewrite, joomla

I moved my website to a new CMS and some of my URLs look different now, so I want to delete a part of incoming URLs so that links to my page still work properly.

The old URL looks like:

```
www.example.com/MY-FORUM/my-forum/category/postingtitle
```

I want to get rid of the `MY-FORUM`, so it looks like:

```
www.example.com/my-forum/category/postingtitle
```

After reading through different posts I tried the following:

```
RewriteRule ^MY-FORUM/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Which gives me back an error message stating:

> Infinite loop detected in JError

(I'm using joomla)

What is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are defining it in the `<VirtualHost>`, so the pattern must have a leading slash:

```
RewriteRule ^/MY-FORUM/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Although if the original rule didn't match then presumably the OP wouldn't be getting an "infinite loop".

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you are getting a Joomla error would suggest that you are already getting past mod_rewrite. By itself, the above directive should not generate a redirect loop - assuming you don't have URLs that start `/MY-FORUM/MY-FORUM/`?

However, Joomla itself uses mod_rewrite, so it's possible there is a conflict with other directives. Since this is an *external redirect* it should come near the start of your script, after the `RewriteEngine On` directive and before any of Joomla's internal rewrites.